# Removing a link below from footer

Tags: footer

My blog http://MyTechFlow.Com having a link below ie: after footer its due to a link in child thems function.php

I want to remove it but dont know what to remove & what to keep.

Below is the text part of function.php plz suggest me to which line and symbol to remove so that it will remove that link from my footers below part....

```
$background ? 'url('. $background .')' : '',
        $color ? '#'. $color : 'transparent', 
        get_theme_mod( 'background_repeat', 'repeat' ), 
        get_theme_mod( 'background_position_x', 'left' ), 
        get_theme_mod( 'background_attachment', 'scroll' ) 
    ) );
} 
function addcopy() {
echo '<b href="http://www.Ariyan.org">Wordpress</a>';
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'addcopy' );
//* Add support for 3-column footer widgets
add_theme_support( 'genesis-footer-widgets', 3 );
```

I want to remove aariyan.org link and also it doesn't left any space after the main footer exit.

Answer (score 2):

The part you need to remove is this: `add_action( 'wp_footer', 'addcopy' );`. Or remove it  with `remove_action`, like so:

```
remove_action('wp_footer','addcopy');
```

However, if your theme has included this link in such a way that you cannot easily remove it-- that is, cannot remove it with a theme option without hacking the code-- then there is probably something in the Terms of Use saying you can't remove it.

**Get a different theme.** In addition to violating the terms, I don't trust themes (or plugins) that force link-backs on the front end. You don't know what else they might be hiding.

Comment: If this solved the question please [mark it as "Accepted"](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer). Look for the check mark on the left.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get rid of this first of all we need to ascertain which plugin or theme is causing this.

usually all nulled plugins which are downloaded from ariyan.org or fellow websites are injected with this code.

Include files of that plugin should be thoroughly checked (like activate.php, or shortcode.php).

just remove the  full code and get trouble free.

```
function addcopy() {
    echo '<b href="http://www.Ariyan.org">Wordpress</a>';
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'addcopy' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Putting this in your `stylesheet.css` did it for me.

```
div.pngfix a[href="http://www.ariyan.org"] {
  display:none;
}
```

Comment: I don't think doing it this way is a good idea; the link will still be visible in the source code and there is probably a good reason why there is no option to remove this as @s_ha_dum pointed out very well in his answer...